# Operation function for "List" in Rcpp - like "Reduce function" in R

Tags: c++, r, list, rcpp, operation

I am new in Rcpp. I am wondering how I can sum elements of "List" up effectively. I want to know some operation functions for it like `Reduce()` in R. 
For example,

```
A=list(c(1,2,3,4),c(-1,1,0,-2))
B=Reduce('+',A)
```

It gives `B=c(0,3,3,2)`.
Thanks.

Comment: Is it guaranteed the list's vector elements will be of the same length? If so, I would think it would be more natural if the vectors in the list were instead columns of a matrix. Then you could accomplish this pretty easily. If not, what should be the behavior when the vectors are of different length?

Comment: Oh, because I want to sum matrices consists of "List". For example,
'A=list(matrix(c(1,2,3,4),nrow=2),matrix(c(-1,1,0,-2),nrow=2))
B=Reduce('+',A)'
It gives 'B=matrix(c(0,3,3,2),nrow=2)'
Thanks

Comment: If it is only the sum on numeric matrices you want, it would be easy. If you want to be more generic, it would be harder.

Answer (score 1):

In the future, you should include what you have tried so far and why it didn't work or explain where you're stuck. This should do what you want it to do as you've clarified in comments (sum numeric matrices that are stored in a List):

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix Rcpp_matrix_List_sum(List x) {
    int n = x.size();
    NumericMatrix result = as<NumericMatrix>(x[0]);
    for ( int i = 1; i < n; ++i ) {
        result += as<NumericMatrix>(x[i]);
    }
    return result;
}

/*** R
A <- list(matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4), nrow = 2), matrix(c(-1, 1, 0, -2), nrow = 2))
Rcpp_matrix_List_sum(A)
*/
```

Result:

```
> A <- list(matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4), nrow = 2), matrix(c(-1, 1, 0, -2), nrow = 2))

> Rcpp_matrix_List_sum(A)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    3
[2,]    3    2
```

NOTE:

This assumes that every element of the List `x` is in fact a `NumericMatrix`. If this is not the case, an error will be thrown.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's very helpful!